# Translating SQL Server Cursor to Azure Synapse

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I have the following code that loops through a table with unique model numbers and creates a new table that contains, for each model numbers, a row based on the year and week number. How can I translate this so it doesn't use a cursor?

```
DECLARE @current_model varchar(50);

--declare a cursor that iterates through model numbers in ItemInformation table
DECLARE model_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT model from ItemInformation
--start the cursor
OPEN model_cursor
--get the next (first value)
FETCH NEXT FROM model_cursor INTO @current_model;

DECLARE @year_counter SMALLINT;
DECLARE @week_counter TINYINT;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) --fetch status returns the status of the last cursor, if 0 then there is a next value (FETCH statement was successful)
BEGIN
    SET @year_counter = 2019;
    WHILE (@year_counter <= Datepart(year, Getdate() - 1) + 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @week_counter = 1;
        WHILE (@week_counter <= 52)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.ModelCalendar(
                model,
                sales_year,
                sales_week
            )
            VALUES(
                @current_model,
                @year_counter,
                @week_counter
            )
            SET @week_counter = @week_counter + 1   
        END
        SET @year_counter = @year_counter + 1
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM model_cursor INTO @current_model
END;
CLOSE model_cursor;
DEALLOCATE model_cursor;
```

If ItemInformation contains the following table:

```
model,invoice
a,4.99
b,9.99
c,1.99
d,8.99
```

then the expected output is:

```
model,sales_year,sales_week
A,2019,1
A,2019,2
A,2019,3
...
A,2019,52
A,2020,1
A,2020,2
A,2020,3
...
A,2020,51
A,2020,52
A,2020,53 (this is 53 because 2020 is leap year and has 53 weeks)
A,2021,1
A,2021,2
...
A,2022,1
A,2022,2
...
A,2022,52
B,2019,1
B,2019,2
...
D, 2022,52
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data (as DDL/DML) and expected results.

Comment: Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops

Comment: You don't need a cursor, you just need a cross join to a calendar table. Step 1: Create a table containing all of the years and weeks in it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yup I have it open on another tab. Here is where I get lost: `'UPDATE STATISTICS '+QUOTENAME([name]) AS sql_code`. I am pretty new to SQL thought process

Comment: @kindofhungry I've added another solution which uses more basic SQL - I hate to see anyone using a loop in SQL :) I'd be curious to know whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table to temporary calendar table containing all the weeks and years. To account for leap years, I took the last 7 days of a year and got the ISO week for each day. To know how many weeks are in a year, I put these values into another temp table and took the max value of it. Azure Synapse doesn't support multiple values in one insert so it looks a lot longer than it should be. I also have to declare each as variable since Synapse can only insert literal or variable. I then cross-joined with my ItemInformation table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_dates 
  ( 
     year SMALLINT, 
     week TINYINT 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE #temp_weeks 
  ( 
     week_num TINYINT 
  ); 

DECLARE @year_counter SMALLINT 

SET @year_counter = 2019 

DECLARE @week_counter TINYINT 

WHILE ( @year_counter <= Datepart(year, Getdate() - 1) + 2 ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @week_counter = 1; 

      DECLARE @day_1 TINYINT 

      SET @day_1 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-25-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_2 TINYINT 

      SET @day_2 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-26-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_3 TINYINT 

      SET @day_3 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-27-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_4 TINYINT 

      SET @day_4 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-28-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_5 TINYINT 

      SET @day_5 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-29-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_6 TINYINT 

      SET @day_6 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-30-', @year_counter)) 

      DECLARE @day_7 TINYINT 

      SET @day_7 = Datepart(isowk, Concat('12-31-', @year_counter)) 

      TRUNCATE TABLE #temp_weeks 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_1) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_2) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_3) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_4) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_5) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_6) 

      INSERT INTO #temp_weeks 
                  (week_num) 
      VALUES      (@day_7) 

      DECLARE @max_week TINYINT 

      SET @max_week = (SELECT Max(week_num) 
                       FROM   #temp_weeks) 

      WHILE ( @week_counter <= @max_week ) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO #temp_dates 
                        (year, 
                         week) 
            VALUES     ( @year_counter, 
                         @week_counter ) 

            SET @week_counter = @week_counter + 1 
        END 

      SET @year_counter = @year_counter + 1 
  END 

DROP TABLE #temp_weeks; 

SELECT i.model, 
       d.year, 
       d.week 
FROM   dbo.iteminformation i 
       CROSS JOIN #temp_dates d 
ORDER  BY model, 
          year, 
          week
DROP TABLE #temp_dates
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE's you can get all combinations of weeks and years within the range required. Then join your data table on.

```
declare @Test table (model varchar(1), invoice varchar(4));

insert into @Test (model, invoice)
values
('a', '4.99'),
('b', '9.99'),
('c', '1.99'),
('d', '8.99');

with Week_CTE as (
  select 1 as WeekNo
  union all
  select 1 + WeekNo
  from Week_CTE 
  where WeekNo < 53
), Year_CTE as (
  select 2019 YearNo
  union all
  select 1 + YearNo
  from Year_CTE 
  where YearNo <= datepart(year, current_timestamp)
)
select T.model, yr.YearNo, wk.WeekNo 
from Week_CTE wk
cross join (
  select YearNo
    -- Find the last week of the year (52 or 53) -- might need to change the start day of the week for this to be correct
    , datepart(week, dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, 1, '01 Jan ' + convert(varchar(4),YearNo)))) LastWeek
  from Year_CTE yr
) yr
cross join (
  -- Assuming only a single row per model is required, and the invoice column can be ignored
  select model
  from @Test
  group by model
) T
where wk.WeekNo <= yr.LastWeek
order by yr.YearNo, wk.WeekNo;
```

As you have advised that using a recursive CTE is not an option, you can try using a CTE without recursion:

```
with T(N) as (
  select X.N
  from (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) X(N)
), W(N) as (
  select top (53) row_number() over (order by @@version) as N
  from T T1
  cross join T T2
), Y(N) as (
  -- Upper limit on number of years
  select top (12) 2018 + row_number() over (order by @@version) AS N
  from T T1
  cross join T T2
)
select W.N as WeekNo, Y.N YearNo, T.model
from W
cross join (
  select N
    -- Find the last week of the year (52 or 53) -- might need to change the start day of the week for this to be correct
    , datepart(week, dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, 1, '01 Jan ' + convert(varchar(4),N)))) LastWeek
  from Y
) Y
cross join (
  -- Assuming only a single row per model is required, and the invoice column can be ignored
  select model
  from @Test
  group by model
) T
-- Filter to required number of years.
where Y.N <= datepart(year, current_timestamp) + 1
and W.N <= Y.LastWeek
order by Y.N, W.N, T.model;
```

Note: If you setup your sample data in future with the DDL/DML as shown here you will greatly assist people attempting to answer.

Comment: thanks dale, will keep in mind that is how to present sample data

Comment: Recursive CTE are not supported in azure synapse, but that is ok. I was able to take some ideas from your answer and make it work. One part that I cannot get is the number of ISO weeks in a given year. Any tips on that? I tried something like `DECLARE @year_counter SMALLINT
DECLARE @week_counter TINYINT

SET @year_counter = 2019
select DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-31-',@year_counter))` but this doesn't always work since sometimes the Dec 31 is part of next year.

Comment: Yeah I wondered whether it would be supported. So is it just a case of checking whether a year is a leap year? Thats fairly straightforward.

Comment: Here is a hack that I thought of: `select (DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-25-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-26-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-27-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-28-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-29-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-30-',@year_counter)), DATEPART(isowk, concat('12-31-',@year_counter)))`. Just need to figure out how to select the column which has the maximum value. If it falls under week 52, 53, or week 1 of next year I can know when I do some type of max function.

Comment: I am using a while loop with incrementing year_counter to insert into a new table with all the weeks for each year then I will cross join

Comment: I want to thank you for helping me, but I your answer was too complicated for me to understand since I am new. I have posted the answer that works for me taking into some parts that you helped me with. Feel free to edit the answer, to make it more efficient.

Comment: Did you try my non-recursive CTE?

Comment: I did. Here is what I got: `Parse error at line: 3, column: 8: Incorrect syntax near '('.` All I did was change @Test to dbo.ItemInformation

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: All flavours of SQL have a reference document somewhere which lists and explains what you can and can't so. If I can see the Synapse SQL reference doc I might be able to fix my code for you.

Comment: I don't know where exactly to find that. I had this database in sql server and now I am migrating over to synapse. I just copy the code and then find how to adapt each part of the error to synapse syntax. I am not sure if it is worth the effort since I already have a working solution that is good enough for me. It still follows T-SQL syntax but some things are just not supported yet (like table variables) which require other creative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to see a loop solution where a set solution can be found. So here goes Take II with no `CTE`, no `values` and no `row_number()` (the table variable is just to simulate your data so not part of the actual solution):

```
declare @Test table (model varchar(1), invoice varchar(4));

insert into @Test (model, invoice)
values
('a', '4.99'),
('b', '9.99'),
('c', '1.99'),
('d', '8.99');

select Y.N + 2019 YearNumber, W.WeekNumber, T.Model
from (
  -- Cross join 5 * 10, then filter to 52/53 as required
  select W1.N * 10 + W2.N + 1 WeekNumber
  from (
    select 0 N
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
  ) W1
  cross join (
    select 0 N
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
  ) W2
) W
-- Cross join number of years required, just ensure its more than will ever be needed then filter back
cross join (
  select 0 N
  union all select 1
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
  union all select 6
  union all select 7
  union all select 8
  union all select 9
) Y
cross join (
  -- Assuming only a single row per model is required, and the invoice column can be ignored
  select model
  from @Test
  group by model
) T
-- Some filter to restrict the years
where Y.N <= 3
-- Some filter to restrict the weeks
and W.WeekNumber <= 53
order by YearNumber, WeekNumber;
```

Comment: Hey Dale, this is really fast and almost worked for me, but the week numbers are not correct. It is showing:
`2019, 51
2020, 51
2021, 51
2022, 51
2019, 52
2020, 52
2021, 52
2022, 52
2019, 53
2020, 53
2021, 53
2022, 53
2019, 1
2020, 1
2021, 1
2022, 1`
when only 2020 should have 53 weeks

Comment: Also if in the future I want to have years after 2022, how would I modify this?

Comment: I left those as exercises for you :) I'm not even sure how you are working out the 52/53 week thing. So just add a filter which works out how many weeks the year has, and the filters accordingly - like I did in my other solution. As for the number of year, modify the filter `Y.N < 3` to to be higher i.e. include more years. Currently it supports 9, but you can add more rows to the years sub-query as desired. There comments in the code to explain this.